# How to show multiple link in one webView from a fragment by putExtra getExtra

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-webview

I want to show multiple link in one webView from a fragment using putExtra getExtra but my code doesn't work.

```
    facebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Link", urls[0]);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your WebViewActivity, just use these two lines in `onCreateMethod()`.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String link = intent.getStringExtra("Link");
```

After that use this `link` to load webpage in your webview.

Comment: I used this two lines but it still doesn't work.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        mytoolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        pb = findViewById(R.id.pb);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String website = intent.getStringExtra("links");

Comment: add code of your WebViewActivity, just edit your question and add code of your WebViewActivity